# Postgres Where Statement for new Table

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres database. In this database is have a Table with Polygons. 
Named: dg_mm_polygons.

I have created a Select and WHERE Query:

```
SELECT * FROM dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons WHERE OFFSHORE = 2;
```

If I execute this it works as i want. 
I want to let the table dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons be as it is.

My Question:
I want to create/get a new table dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons_2. If data is saved in dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons in needs to be given/get to the table dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons_2.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CREATE TABLE AS statement (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

In your case, the following statement will create a new table called "dg_mm_polygons2", which will be populated with data from your existing "dg_mm_polygons" table where OFFHSORE = 2.

```
CREATE TABLE dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons2 AS SELECT * FROM dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons WHERE OFFSHORE = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want to create a view dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons_2 which contains only a subset of data from dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons

```
 create view dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons_2 as 
 select * 
 from dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons 
 WHERE OFFSHORE = 2;
```

this will ensure that only values of offshore = 2 show up in dg_geodata.dg_mm_polygons_2. be carefult though, you can also insert update/delete from views just as you would from the original table.